# How did Hisoka make the examinee's arms disappear?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

[image]

Hisoka's Nen ability is [Bungee Gum](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Hisoka#Nen). It creates a flexible substance that sticks to objects and makes them pullable at demand.

[image] [image] [image]

I don't understand how Hisoka made that exam participant's arms disappear in episode 3 (2011 series).
Can you please explain it?